# Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, npm, mongoose

Whenever I delete my orders and try to fetch again with same id 
it returns an proper response that (Order Not Found) but in console it return an error

```
router.delete("/:orderID", (req, res, next) => {
  const id = req.params.orderID;
  Orders.deleteOne({ _id: id })
    .exec()
    .then(result => {
      if (!result) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "there is no such Order to Delete, Kindly Check Order ID",
          fetchAll: "http://localhost:3000/orders/"
        });
      }
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Order Deleted Successfully",
        request: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/",
          body: {
            productID: "Id of the Product",
            quantity: "Total Quantity of the Product"
          }
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      res.status(500).json({
        error: err
      });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You **can send a response only once per call**.

Once a response is sent, you can not send another response for **"that request"**.

Here, you are sending two responses, one with 200 (success scenario) and another with 404 (error scenario).

As these are two different response for two different purposes,

either keep them in **`if else block`** like this:

```
    if (!result) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "there is no such Order to Delete, Kindly Check Order ID",
          fetchAll: "http://localhost:3000/orders/"
        });
    } else {
      res.status(200).json({
        message: "Order Deleted Successfully",
        request: {
          type: "POST",
          url: "http://localhost:3000/orders/",
          body: {
            productID: "Id of the Product",
            quantity: "Total Quantity of the Product"
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Or just **`return`** as shown in one of the ans.

```
    if (!result) {
        res.status(404).json({
          message: "there is no such Order to Delete, Kindly Check Order ID",
          fetchAll: "http://localhost:3000/orders/"
        });

        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return after you sent the 404, otherwise you're first sending 404 and then 200. Since the code will just keep going.

```
if (!result) {
  res.status(404).json({
    message: "there is no such Order to Delete, Kindly Check Order ID",
    fetchAll: "http://localhost:3000/orders/"
  });
  return;
}
```

Comment: DELETE /orders/5dbd5c94f15dce21b4859659 200 117.300 ms - 188
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
    at ServerResponse.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:470:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (C:\Users\Manav\Documents\Github\RESTful-